# What is Scala REPL's tab completion telling me here?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop, tab-completion, scala-2.9

While working my way through Cay S. Horstmann's "Scala for the Impatient", I noticed something interesting revealed by the first exercise in the first chapter.

1. In the Scala REPL, type 3. followed by the Tab key.  What methods can be applied?

When I do this, I get the following

```
scala> 3.
%              &              *              +              -              /              
>              >=             >>             >>>            ^              asInstanceOf   
isInstanceOf   toByte         toChar         toDouble       toFloat        toInt          
toLong         toShort        toString       unary_+        unary_-        unary_~        
|
```

But I noticed that if I hit Tab a second time, I get a slightly different list.

```
scala> 3.
!=             ##             %              &              *              +              
-              /                            >=             >>             >>>            ^              asInstanceOf   
equals         getClass       hashCode       isInstanceOf   toByte         toChar         
toDouble       toFloat        toInt          toLong         toShort        toString       
unary_+        unary_-        unary_~        |
```

What is the REPL trying to tell me here?  Is there something special about the different methods that appear the second time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hitting tab twice in the REPL [raises the verbosity of the completion](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/CompletionAware.html):

> If "methodName" is among `z`'s completions, and `verbosity > 0` indicating
>   tab has been pressed twice consecutively, then we call `alternativesFor`
>   and show a list of overloaded method signatures.

The following methods from the [interpreter source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/JLineCompletion.scala) indicate what's filtered for method completion when `verbosity == 0` (i.e., when you've only hit tab once and aren't getting the `alternativesFor` version):

```
def anyRefMethodsToShow = Set("isInstanceOf", "asInstanceOf", "toString")

def excludeEndsWith: List[String] = Nil

def excludeStartsWith: List[String] = List("<") // <byname>, <repeated>, etc.

def excludeNames: List[String] =
  (anyref.methodNames filterNot anyRefMethodsToShow) :+ "_root_"

def exclude(name: String): Boolean = (
  (name contains "$") ||
  (excludeNames contains name) ||
  (excludeEndsWith exists (name endsWith _)) ||
  (excludeStartsWith exists (name startsWith _))
)
```

So with one tab you're getting the methods filtered by some rules that the interpreter developers have decided are reasonable and useful. Two tabs gives you the unfiltered version.